# Shed floor framing out of square 3/4 inch

Tags: shed

My first time building a shed by myself and it's been a lot of work, since it is on a slope. I got the piers and columns in, had it squared, and put cut plywood in the corners.

I cut all the joists, and I guess exhaustion and rushing, I didn't double check the squareness and I put all the joist hangers on and anchors from the rim joist to the 6x6 posts.. with 16d galvanized nails that are not coming out. Some how it shifted even with the corner braces. Guess plywood was a bad choice for holding square.

It was originally one inch off, but I got it down to 3/4.. knocking it with a 4lb sledge hammer..

What are my options? If I start framing how much will this effect the walls?

[image]

Comment: I'd use an 8 pound sledge, a board to take the hit, and nice long screws. The wood, even 6X6" should bend over time if you secure it well. Nails are likely not your friend where it's out of true that much.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Do i need to worry about cracking any joist with all the hangers in already? Or cracking the 6x6 posts?

Comment: Hitting with an 8lb sledge that is..

Comment: Why worry about this small screw up. Before my dad died he used to say that is what caulking and paint are for! I have worked on some 1940 era houses that were 3" out of square on a 1100 ad home, trying to add a new bed and bath was tough. Some modern 90's and newer homes have been just as bad if not worse. Funny many of the late 1800 and early 1900 homes were closer to square on the outside walls but the internal walls were worse.

Comment: @eaglei22 4Lb sledge sounds to small, but yes, you could damage if you got overenthusiastic with an 8 Lb hammer.

Comment: @EdBeal i don't disagree with you, i just haven't ever framed a big structure like this. I was afraid if i continued maybe i would run into bigger problems because of it. So,, do i need to compensate with adjusting  measurements for the walls? Or just continue to build as normal.

Comment: How did you arrive at 3/4"? If you pulled square lines, and the opposing corner is 3/4" off the line, that's worth a bit of effort to correct (per Paul's suggestions). If you're taking diagonal measurements, you're actually only 3/8" off (half the difference), and it's not worth your time.

Comment: @isherwood yea, i am taking diagonal measurements. And okay, I am asking now before further framing as I wasn't sure if i would run into any serious problems not correcting it. Thanks!

Comment: You can undo the clips at the corners that tie it to the posts and rack it to square. I am more concerned that  your rim joists appear to be single 2x's but i can not tell from the angle of the photo. What is the span between posts?

Comment: @Alaskaman The Shed is 12x10 and the perpendicular rim joists to the inside joists is 12ft 2x8 pressure treated. I am using shed plans and doing what the plans state, not my own. Although i did modify to 6x6 post from 4x4, and putting the rim joist on top of the 6x6, as opposed to nailing to outside as plans suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a ratchet strap or a come-along to pull the corners together on the diagonal that measures longer than the other, then, before removing this, secure a sheet or two of plywood down to the floor joists.

You can use some big eye bolts through the rim joists to give your ratcheting device something to hook into at either end.

You shouldn’t need to worry about damaging anything. 3/4” out of square means you’re compressing the long diagonal only 3/8”, and nails allow for some wiggle and play in the framing before it is sheathed with ply or boards.

I don’t recommend beating on the thing you’re building. It’s hard on your body, and doesn’t hold things precisely square for you while you do the other work to sustain the squareness once achieved, like laying plywood on the floor.

Comment: Thanks paul. Can you give me some more guidance on attaching the ratchet strap? I have some small ones that i can use, but what size eye bolts, and where would i put them? Want to avoid anything flying out at me.

Comment: Don't worry about 3/4" inch in a structure that is already built unless all wood. If all wood it can be corrected but expect your pier blocks to need adjustment

Comment: I would recommend using a larger strap like you might see in use on big trucks. There is no harm in trying the small one you have, but it may not have the strength to pull things square. I would use eye bolts at least 1/2” in diameter, long enough to be installed through the face of the rim joist near the corner, secured with a nut. Washers on both sides would help, especially if you end up having to pull really hard. Don’t use those lag screw eye bolts...